# How "stream" a part of my screen to another part

Tags: user-interface, bitmap, autohotkey

So I have two big monitors. So I want to "stream" a small important part of the right monitor to the left. I have a specific part like 100x200pixels to the right of my screen I want to show at the very left.

I can do this but in a very ineffektive way by getting the bitmap from the right and displaying it in a gui to the left, then putting it in a loop where I create and destroy the gui showing an updated bitmap every 5 seconds. But this causes flickering and seems like a bad solution.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may help and reduce flicker is to use `GuiControl`. In your loop, instead of recreating the GUI each time, just update the picture control's contents.

`GuiControl ,, picture_control_name , %A_Desktop%\updated_pic.bmp`